# How to use existing applications in Android 3.0?

Tags: android

HI,

I read below line in Android 3.0.

**Existing applications can seamlessly participate in the new holographic UI theme without code changes, by adding a single attribute in their manifest files.**

Which attribute can I write in manifest file to use existing application in Android 3.0.Please give me snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link which describes the migration to honeycomp (tablet): http://www.apptility.com/2011/03/how-to-port-an-android-app-to-honeycomb-tablet-ready-version/

(1. describes the manifest-changes)